# How to open and close menu by event 'onMouseOver&onMouseLeave' in React JS Material ui

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner to react JS and I want to show a drop-down list of items whenever a user hovers on the button without having to click on the button for this I have tried this below code but it is not working fine.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Fade from '@mui/material/Fade';
import { Container,Link } from '@mui/material';


function FadeMenu() {

const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleOver = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
setOpen(true);
    }

    const handleLeave = (event) => {
     
        setAnchorEl(null);
        setOpen(false);
    }

    const handleClose = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

 return (

<Button
                id="about-fade-button"
                aria-controls="about-fade-menu"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'about-fade-menu' : 'false'}
                onMouseOver={handleOver}
                onMouseLeave={handleLeave}
                sx={{cursor:"pointer",textTransform:"none",fontSize:"14px",
                '&:hover':{color:"#30B54B",textDecoration:"underline",
            textDecorationThickness:"2px"},}}
            >
                About
            </Button>
            <Menu
                id="about-fade-menu"
                MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'about-fade-button',
                }}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                TransitionComponent={Fade}
            >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>2</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>3</MenuItem>
            </Menu>



            <Button
                id="helpcenter-fade-button"
                aria-controls="helpcenter-fade-menu"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'helpcenter-fade-menu' : 'false'}
                onMouseOver={handleOver}
                onMouseLeave={handleLeave}
                sx={{cursor:"pointer",textTransform:"none",fontSize:"14px",
                '&:hover':{color:"#30B54B",textDecoration:"underline",textDecorationStyle:"solid",
            textDecorationThickness:"2px"},}}
            >
                Help Center
            </Button>
            <Menu
                id="helpcenter-fade-menu"
                MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'helpcenter-fade-button',
                }}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                TransitionComponent={Fade}
            >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>4</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>5</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>6</MenuItem>
            </Menu>

);

}

export default FadeMenu;
```

I have referred this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912870/how-to-open-material-ui-menu-when-hover-on-a-button) and here showing only `onMouseOver` event but I want to use `onMouseOver&onMouseLeave` this two events when use `Over and Leave` the button.

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'open' variable propely. Now it's doing nothing. For example:

```
{open && <Menu>...</Menu>}
```

which means if open is true show Menu component. Same you can do for any element.

Comment: Hi @xGrahir I'm not clear about your answer can plz give me some more info on this it better to understand to me bcoz I'm very new to this react JS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).